# Why do some website have the same formatting when JSON data is returned?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

If you go to the `datamuse` website:
http://www.datamuse.com/api/ and select some of the example of links e.g. the first link `'words with a meaning similar to ringing in the ears'` then the request is returned in `Firefox` with a black screen and a few tabs at the top (`JSON`, `Raw Data`, `Headers`). In `Chrome`, however, the data is returned with a non formatted style about it.

I have accessed different websites in the past where `Firefox` has displayed the data similar to the one with the black screen and want to know what's going on. Is there some sort of special formatting that can be applied to `JSON` data in `Firefox` to give it that look when the data is requested?

I'm struggling to find the right way to ask this question.

Comment: So Firefox is showing JSON data in a browser. Set the right content headers and it should be fine.

Comment: probably you have some extensions that detects json and formats it for you (there are also extensions like this for chrome)

Comment: The first Google result for "firefox json": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer (not trying to be rude, just pointing out that you were overthinking ways to find the answer ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firefox 53, that browser has had a [JSON viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer) built-in and enabled by default.

Any JSON document (served with the correct Content-Type header) will be formatted that way by the browser.